# Why is the bytestring 0xaa21a9ed used as the witness commitment header in SegWit?

Tags: segregated-witness, coinbase-transaction, witness-commitment

As per [BIP 141](https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0141.mediawiki#commitment-structure), the witness Merkle root hash is stored in a `scriptPubkey` field of a coinbase transaction output with a header consisting of the 4-byte string `0xaa21a9ed`. What is the reasoning behind choosing this string?

Googling only yielded a reference to namecoin on a [bitcoin-dev IRC log](http://bitcoinstats.com/irc/bitcoin-dev/logs/2015/12/14#l1450098707.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's random.

The intent was choosing something long enough to avoid having someone accidentally create an output that matches, but short enough that it doesn't unnecessarily makes SegWit blocks larger.

Comment: Why was it not chosen to be some regular 4-byte string like all zeros or all ones or `0xAABBCCDD`? Will the probability of someone creating a null data output which matches the header increase if the header had some regular structure?